# Can Laravel 5 handle 1000 concurrent users without lagging badly?

Tags: php, laravel, performance, laravel-5

I wanted to know that if 1000 users are concurrently using a website built with laravel 5 and also querying database regularly then how does laravel 5 perform ?
I know it would be slow but will it be highly slow that it would be unbearable ?
Note that i am also going to use ajax a lot.

And lets assume i am using digital ocean cloud service with following configurations

```
2GB memory
2 vCPU
40GB SSD
```

I don't expect completely real figures as it is impossible to do so but at least provide some details whether i should go with laravel with some considerable performance.

Please also provide some some tools through which i can check the speed of my laravel 5 application as well as how it will perform when there is actual load as well as other tools through which i can test speed and performance.

And it would be great if someone has real experience of using laravel especially Laravel 5.

And what about Lumen does that really make application faster than laravel and how much ?

Comment: Perhaps that has more to do with your server specs than with Laravel, though I would probably bet it does not. PHP alone has a bad reputation on it's performance, you put a framework on top of that it's easy to tell where it's going.

Comment: It isn't going to be possible to definitively answer this question without a deep dive into your app - it will depend on what your app does, how IO, Thread, CPU + memory intensive it is, how much caching it uses, and the hardware and number of servers used to support it. Not to mention how frequently each user needs to make Ajax calls.

Comment: I have multiple routes set up in laravel. Peak memory usage ranges from 1mb to ~30mb per request and database request range from 1 to 10 per request. You need to profile your application based on these fugures to figure out what an average user does and then scale that up by 1000. We can't help you do that because it's entirely use case specific. The framework itself is pretty lightweight.

Comment: If you want performance, you should avoid Laravel. CodeIgniter seems to be fast. Check [this](https://medium.com/@asked_io/php-mvc-framework-showdown-7-1-performance-2da52ac9fcba) out.

Comment: @Olivier That's a "Hello World" benchmark! are you going to only output "Hello World" to your users? the results will be very different when you benchmark a full application with Auth etc written in different frameworks...
I'm not saying Laravel will be faster than CI, just that the linked Benchmark is not applicable here.

Comment: @J.Doe Of course, for real apps, the gap between Laravel and CI won't be as large as in that simple benchmark. But CI will most likely perform better.

Answer (score 16):

In short, yes. At least newer versions of Laravel are capable **(Laravel 7.*)**.
That being said, this is really a *three* part conundrum.

---

#### **1. Laravel (Php)**

- **[High Concurrency Architecture And Laravel Performance Tuning](https://www.slideshare.net/chtalbert/high-concurrency-architecture-and-laravel-performance-tuning)**

---

Honestly, I wouldn't be able to provide half the details as this amazing article provides. He's got everything in there from the definition of **concurrency** all the way to `pre-optimization times vs. after-optimization times.`

---

---

#### **2. Reading, Writing, & Partitioning Persisted Data (Databases)**

- **[MySQL vs. MongoDB](https://www.simform.com/mongodb-vs-mysql-databases/)**

---

I'd be curious if the real concern is Php's Laravel, or more of a database read/write speed timing bottleneck. Non relational databases are an incredible technology, that benefit big data much more than traditional relational databases.

- Non-relational Databases (Mongo) have a much faster read speed than MySql (Something like 60% faster if I'm remembering correctly)
- Non-relational Databases (Mongo) do have a slower write speed, but this usually is not an inhibitor to the user experience
- Unlike Relational Databases (MySQL), Mongo DB can **truly** be partitioned, spread out across multiple servers.
- Mongo DB has collections of documents, collections are pretty synonymous to tables and documents are pretty synonymous to rows.
- The difference being, MongoDB has a very JSON like feel to it. (Collections of documents, where each document looks like a JSON object).
- The huge difference, and benefit, is that each document - AKA row - does not have have the same keys. When using mongo DB on a fortune 500 project, my mentor and lead at the time, Logan, had a phenomenal quote.

> *"**Mongo Don't Care**"*

This means that you can shape the data how you're wanting to retrieve it, so not only is your read speed faster, you're usually not being slowed by having to retrieve data from multiple tables.

Here's a package, personally tested and loved, to set up MongoDB within Laravel

- [Jessengers ~ MongoDB In Laravel](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

If you are concerned about immense amounts of users and transferring data, MongoDB may be what you're looking for. With that, let's move on to the 3rd, and most important point.

---

#### **3. Serverless Architecture (Aka Horizontal scaling)**

---

Aws, Google Cloud, Microsoft Azure, etc... I'm sure you've hear of ***The Cloud***.

This, ultimately, is what you're looking for if you're having concurrency issues and want to stay within the realm of Laravel.

It's a whole new world of incredible tools one can hammer away at -- they'er awesome. It's also a whole new, quite large, world of tools and thought to learn.

First, let's dive into a few **serverless** concepts.

- Infrastructure as Code **[Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/)**

  > *"Use Infrastructure as Code to provision and manage any cloud, infrastructure, or service"*
- Horizontal Scaling Example via **The Cloud**

  > *"Create a Laravel application. It's a single application, monolithic. Then you dive Cloud. You discover Terraform. Ahaha, first you use terraform to define how many **instances** of your app will run at once. You decide you want 8 instances of your application. Next, you of course define a **Load Balancer**. The Load Balancer simply balances the traffic load between your 8 application instances. Each application is connected to the same database, ultimately sharing the same data source. You're simply spreading out the traffic across multiples instances of the same application."*
- We can of course top that, very simplified answer of cloud, and dive into lambdas, the what **Not** to do's of serverless, setting up your internal virtual cloud network...

**Or...we can thank the Laravel team in advance for simplifying Serverless Architecture**

- Yep, Laravel Simplified Serverless (Shout out Laravel team)

  - **[Serverless Via Laravel Vapor](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/introduction.html#what-is-vapor)**

**Laravel Vapor Opening Paragraph**

> "*Laravel Vapor is an auto-scaling, serverless deployment platform for Laravel, powered by AWS Lambda. Manage your Laravel infrastructure on Vapor and fall in love with the scalability and simplicity of serverless.*"

---

### Coming to a close, let's summarize.

**Oringal Concern**

> *Ability to handle a certain amount of traffic in a set amount of time*

**Potential Bottlenecks with potential solutions**

**Laravel & Php**

- ([High Concurrency Architecture And Laravel Performance
  Tuning](https://www.slideshare.net/chtalbert/high-concurrency-architecture-and-laravel-performance-tuning)

**Database & Persisting/Retrieving Data Efficiently**

- [Jessengers ~ MongoDB In Laravel](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

**Serverless Architecture For Horizontal Scaling**

- [Serverless Via Laravel Vapor](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/introduction.html#what-is-vapor)

Comment: I would like to add that caching can help you a lot. I currently use caching when I need to retrieve and work on the iterated data, so only the first user performing the request will notice a delay... hence, it's also a matter of how you code

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer this based on my experience as a software developer. To be honest I definitely will ask for an upgrade whenever it hits 1000 concurrent users at the same time because I won't take a risk with server failure nor data failure.

But let's break it how to engineer this.

1. It could handle those users if the data fetched is not complex and there are not many operations from Laravel code. If it's just passing through from the database and almost no modification from the data, it'll be fast.
2. The data fetched by the users are not unique. Let's say you have a news site without user personalization. the news that the users fetched mostly will be the same. You cached the data from memory (Redis, *which I recommend*) or from the web server(Nginx, *should be avoided*), your Laravel program will run fast enough.
3. Querying directly from the database is faster than using Laravel ORM. you might consider it if needed, but I myself will always try to use ORM because it will help code to be more readable and secure.
4. Splitting database, web server, CDN, and cache server is obviously making it easier to monitor server usage.
5. Try to upgrade it to the latest version. I used to work with a company that using version 5, and it's not really good at performance.
6. opcode caching. cache the PHP file code. I myself never use this.
7. split app to backend and frontend. use state management for front end app to reduce requests data to the server.

Now let's answer your question

Are there any tools for checking performance? You can check Laravel debug bar, these tools provide for simple performance reports. I myself encourage you to make a test for each of the features you create. You can create a report from that unit test to find which feature taking time to finish.

Are lume faster than laravel? Yeah, Lumen is faster because they disabled some features from Laravel. But please be aware that Taylor seems gonna [stop Lumen for development](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1631). You should consider this for the future.

If you're aware of performance, you might not choose Laravel for development.

1. Because there is a delay between each server while opening a connection. Whenever a user creating a request, they open a connection to the server. server open connections to the cache server, database server, SMTP server, or probably other 3rd parties as well. It's the real bottleneck that happened on Laravel. You can make `keep-alive` connections with the database and cache server to reduce connection delay, but you wouldn't find it in Laravel because it will dispose the connection whenever the request finish.
2. It's a typed language, mostly compiled language are faster

In the end, you might not be able to use Laravel with that server resources unless you're creating a really simple application.

Answer (score 2):

A question like this need an answer with real numbers:

luckily this [guy](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/benchmarking-laravel-symfony-zend-2c01c2b270f8) already have done it in similar conditions as you want to try and with laravel forge.

with this php config:

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=512
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=64
opcache.max_accelerated_files=20000
opcache.validate_timestamps=0
opcache.save_comments=1
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

the results:

```
Without Sessions:
Laravel: 609.03 requests per second
With Sessions:
Laravel: 521.64 requests per second
```

so answering your question:

With that memory you would be in trouble to get 1000 users making requests, use 4gb memory and you will be in better shape.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with Laravel.

I tried benchmarking Laravel with an 8 core CPU, 8 GB RAM and 120GB HDD and I just got 200-400 request per second.

Comment: For comparison, our applications use custom frameworks and handle 500 requests per second per server without panicking. One application runs on 2vCPU/4GB and another on 4vCPU/8GB - both are "normal" involving databases etc and full suite of logging/error handling etc, but it shows that it depends on the application. But Laravel contains a lot of bloat; wonderful if you want to quickly knock up an application or not worry about internals, but not if you need performance.